# Paragraph outside of a Div with height auto

Tags: html, css

Codepen link: https://codepen.io/cadegord/pen/qXMzBZ?editors=1111

I'm trying to make a little user review div element inside of it is lorem placeholder text, I try and set height to auto and the text ignores div and goes outside of it.

Is this due to my centering code of

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

or could it be the use of

```
transform: translateY();
```

Comment: If I got it right, your problem is that you put the paragraph inside the `circle` class and this has a fixed height of `100px`. Try to move the paragraph out of the circle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have your text inside the `<div class='circle'>`, which has a fixed height of `100px`.

You can just move the `<p>` tag out of `<div class='circle'>` and place it in `<div class="container">`. Try running the snippet below, or check out this **[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/dankreiger5/pen/ayagXW?editors=1111)**:

```css
body {
  margin-top: 10%;
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
}

.container {
  border: 2px solid #DFE0E2;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px #A2AEBB;
  border-radius: 30px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 500px;
  min-height: auto;
  background-color: white;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.circle {
  margin: auto;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #20A39E, #7FE6A2);
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-100px);
}

.quote {
  font-size: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  transform: translateY(5px);
}

.contents {
  font-family: "Robto", Arial;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="circle">
    <h1 class="quote">“</h1>

  </div>
  <p class="contents">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem quod reprehenderit, accusantium architecto voluptatum voluptates aut aliquam magnam.</p>
</div>
```

I also set `text-align: center;` on your `.contents` element so that the text has a nice center alignment inside of the container.

Comment: Worked perfectly can't believe I made such a trivial error.

Answer (score 1):

Inside you quote `div` you have a `h1` tag that has margin

Removing the margin from the `h1` inside the quote div will solve you the problem

```
.quote h1{
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```css
body{
  margin-top: 10%;
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
}

.container {
  border: 2px solid #DFE0E2;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px #A2AEBB;
  border-radius: 30px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 500px;
  min-height: 400px;
  background-color: white;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.circle {
  margin: auto;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #20A39E, #7FE6A2);
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-100px);
}

.quote {
  font-size: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  transform: translateY(5px);
}
.quote h1{
 margin-bottom: 0;
}
.contents {
  font-family: "Robto", Arial;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="circle">
     <h1 class="quote">“</h1>
  <p class="contents">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem quod reprehenderit, accusantium architecto voluptatum voluptates aut aliquam magnam.</p>
   </div>
</div>
```